Why did Jesus compare himself to Green Tree in Lk 23:31?
We hear Jesus telling the women of Jerusalem who had come to meet him on his way to Calvary, Lk 23:31(KJV):

For if they do these things in a green tree, what shall be done in the dry?

Jesus' words could imply various  things, for instance:(i)Jesus  was conveying that the sufferings inflicted on his body were too much to bear ; (ii) He was foretelling that his followers would be subject to much more suffering than was inflicted on him ;and (iii) He was quoting from the scriptures to affirm his willingness to suffer further.
My question is: How do Bible scholars explain Lk 23:31 ?  Are there any extrabiblical writings on the topic  ?

"Wood" is better a than "tree" here. I don't think Jesus is referring to himself. He is speaking about the situation of Jerusalem, in which a revolutionary fervor that was still "green" would burst into flame in 66-70 a.d. At that time the Romans destroyed Jerusalem, fulfilling the prophecy in vs 30. The issue has already been addressed previously... https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/89708/is-the-warning-to-the-women-on-the-via-dolorosa-a-repeat-of-the-olivet-discourse https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/67121/symbolism-of-green-wood-and-the-dry/67122#67122

BTW... the Herod's temple was still under construction at this time. It had been finished prior the Great Jewish Revolt that resulted in its destruction by fire.  this may lie behind the green wood/dry wood analogy. Jesus' was  executed as an alleged rebel against Rome, but the Romans would carry out a persecution on a massive scale a generation later forcing Jews to flee the city.

In Verse 30, Jesus was quoting Hosea 10:8 ( See Footnote  of NIV ). I couldn't lay hands on any footnote giving a cross OT reference of Verse 31. It could have come from some Jewish texts, not included in OT. By the way, some oriental languages have the same word for ' raw' and ' green ' . Modern scientists have come up with experiments to prove that green ( live) trees can feel danger and send signals to other trees. One case is of the food poisoning of Giraffes which had grazed in a focussed locality, instigating the trees to produce poison in their leaves.

Thanks, Dan Fefferman, for providing link to connected Qs. The second question having direct link to Lk 23:31 has not  yet  'green- ticked ' an answer. Could you frame one ?

Comparison I would submit for consideration, that the comparison is not of Jesus with "green wood", but present Jewish peaceful culture  with "green wood".   In the future  "dry wood" times there was going to be a "hot time in town, with enflamed rioting and the scorching and sweltering heat of injustice rampant throughout!

The operative word in Luke 23:31 is ξύλον (xulon) which simply means "wood" and by extension, anything made of wood such as a tree, club, plank, etc.  It occurs 20 times in the NT whose uses can be classified as follows:

"tree", Luke 23:31, Rev 2:7, 18:12, 22:2, 14, 19.
"club", Matt 26:47, 55, Mark 14:43, 48, Luke 22:52,
"wooden beam (ie, cross)", Acts 5:30, 10:39, 13:29, Gal 3:13, 1 Peter 2:24
"stocks", Acts 16:24
"wood", 1 Cor 3:12, Rev 18:12

Among these instances, Luke 23:31 is unique for a case of metaphoric use.  The OP's question essentially revolves around who/what the metaphor points to.
There has been much debate about what this metaphor means.  For example:

the tree represents Rome (eg, Ellicott) and what will happen when Rome sacks Jerusalem
the tree represents Israel in rejecting Messiah and what will occur when Israel finally rejects the covenant (eg, Cambridge)
the tree represents Jesus (eg, Pulpit commentary and Barnes)

IMHO, I think the second option above is closest to the facts especially in view of the context of the previous few verses.

Thanks, Dottard. Would you mind writing a line or two on how Pulpit Commentary and Barnes state that Jesus was referring to himself ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - see  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/luke/23-31.htm

Thanks. Stay blessed.

Green versus DryAs every woodsman knows, green wood does not burn as well or as hot as dry wood. Today we call dry wood, seasoned wood.
[An Aside: Burning Green wood causes creosote to build up in chimneys, so only seasoned wood that is thoroughly dry is used, because it burns hot enough to expel the creosote and prevent a chimney fire.]
In considering Jesus's comment, He is merely stating that if the horrible conduct resulting in a Crucifixion of an innocent person, is done during relatively normal times...just think how corrupt and mean it's going to be in Jerusalem when political events and adverse circumstances really get hot---i.e. when zealots, famine, Roman conquest, etc. happen! That's why Jesus had warned:

Daughters of Jerusalem, weep not for me, but weep for yourselves, and for your children.For behold, the days are coming in the which they shall say, "Blessed are the barren, and the wombs that never bare, and the paps which never gave suck!"Then shall they begin to say to the mountains, "Fall on us", and to the hills, "Cover us." (Luke 23:28-30)

Previously, Jesus had told the men in the Temple before His arrest, a similar message: a lot of horrible events were soon to happen in Jerusalem:

The days will come in which there shall not be left one stone upon another that shall not be thrown down...Nation shall rise against nation...great earthquakes shall be in divers places, and famine, and pestilences...they shall lay hands on you, and persecute you, delivering you up to the synagogues, and into prisons...ye shall be betrayed...and some of you shall they cause to be put to death...for these be the days of vengeance...


But woe to them that are with child...for their shall be great distress in the land, and wrath upon the people, and they shall fall by the edge of the sword, and shall be led away captive... (Luke 21:6-24; Compare Matthew 24)

Josephus HistorianThe Jewish historian left us a vivid description of the horrible conditions that Jesus warned about. (The Jewish Wars)  Instead of just a few incidents of unjust punishment (like Jesus's crucifixion), the whole city of besieged Jerusalem in 70 A.D. was rife with kangaroo courts where thousands of people were condemned...where murderous Zealots ran roughshod over the city, killing at will (especially the rich aristocracy)...where mothers ate their children because of rampant starvation...where Roman soldiers crucified thousands of Jews trying to flee the city...where multitudes of decaying bodies were thrown over the walls because there was no place to bury them...on and on!
If during normal times, injustice would occur (green tree), then during extremely troublesome times (dry kindling, extremely flammable), a whole lot of tyranny was to occur!  It would be a "hot time in town!"
This is the plain meaning of Jesus's warning to the women.
[Note: Jesus was not comparing "Himself" to "green wood", but comparing the "present semi-normal times" to a future period when there would be great, tumultuous times of tragedy.  And if the powers-that-be would act unjustly during quiet times, guess how mean they would act during a time of tremendous upheaval!]

In Luke 23:31, Jesus uses the metaphor of a "green tree" to convey the idea that if the innocent (symbolized by the green tree) suffers, how much worse will it be for the guilty (symbolized by the dry tree). Scholars often interpret this as Jesus warning that if His suffering, as the righteous one, leads to such cruelty, then those who reject God will face even harsher judgment. It als serves as a prophetic statement about the coming destruction of Jerusalem. While extrabiblical writings don't expand directly on this verse, it aligns with Jewish wsdom literature and prophetic traditions about judgment and suffering.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
